# Why Azure Front Door Url Redirect to AppService Url For ReactJs App

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have setup Frontdoor with app service and also deployed the ReactJsapp and Asp.net APIs in the two different subdirectory like site\wwwroot\webapp and site\wwwroot\api. The problem is that when I use the azure frontdoor url example.azurewebfd.net/webapp then It direct to the example.azurewebsite.net/webapp. It works fine for api and It doesn't redirect to the example.azurewebsite.net/api and it keeps example.azurefd.net/api.

How could solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see a solution on this too. I've been researching this topic awhile now, and it seems that there is a lack of reported problems/guides on this matter. It is clearly defined for ApplicationGatway which faces the same problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/troubleshoot-app-service-redirection-app-service-url
Cant seem to find these options for Front Door.